# gradle Could not resolve: org.quickfixj:quickfixj-core

Tags: quickfixj

My build.gradle looks like this

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'eclipse'
}

def quickfixVersion = "2.1.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repo.marketcetera.org/maven"
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    group = 'fix'
    description = 'fix api'

    implementation 'org.quickfixj:quickfixj-core:${quickfixVersion}'
    implementation 'org.quickfixj:quickfixj-msg-fix42:${quickfixVersion}'

    implementation 'org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.1.2'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.3'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.6.3'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}

compileTestJava {
  // exclude 'fix/FixTest.java'
}
```

when I refresh the Gradle project it gets all dependencies except for QuickFixJ with error:

```
Could not resolve: org.quickfixj:quickfixj-core:${quickfixVersion}
Could not resolve: org.quickfixj:quickfixj-msg-fix42:${quickfixVersion}
```

Comment: I'm nor familiar with gradle, but is the error that the variable `quickfixVersion` cannot be resolved or is the question why the dependencies cannot be found? Does it work  when you pass the explicit version just like you do on the other dependencies?

Comment: Oh, just saw that you are using the marketcetera repo. I don't know if that still is maintained for recent versions. Could you try using sonatype? E.g. https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.quickfixj/quickfixj-messages/2.1.1/jar

Comment: yes it's not the version variable, the error is the same with explicit version. So yeah, use Sonatype... except how do I configure Gradle to use Sonatype repo, isn't mavenCentral enough?

Comment: Sorry, I meant maven central (which now is Sonatype). The link I gave you is for maven central.

Comment: Well yes it's there already tho :) maybe this is my gradle version, i don't know why the repo cannot resolve...

Comment: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/quickfixj/quickfixj-messages-fix42/2.1.1/ Edit: yes

Comment: I changed the build gradle repositories to 
`repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }
}`
but still the same could not resolve. Also changed `quickfixj-msg-fix42` to `quickfixj-messages-fix42`

Comment: Could you try https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quickfixj ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }
```

and

```
compile group: 'org.quickfixj', name: 'quickfixj-core', version: '2.1.0'
compile group: 'org.quickfixj', name: 'quickfixj-messages-fix42', version: '2.1.0'
```

instead of the implementation command in build.gradle