# how to convert quickfix project from maven to gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, quickfixj

I am trying to convert the quickfix project from maven to gradle. Tried a simple gradle init. it is not working. Any ideas on how to approach this. Has anyone done this. thanks.

https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj

Comment: just out of curiosity: why?

Comment: it is a firm wide standardization project. using gradle across the board.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/59843192/4962355 ??